# How to find the count of a word in a string

Tags: python, string, split, counter

I have a string "`Hello I am going to I with hello am`". I want to find how many times a word occur in the string. Example hello occurs 2 time. I tried this approach that only prints characters -

```
def countWord(input_string):
    d = {}
    for word in input_string:
        try:
            d[word] += 1
        except:
            d[word] = 1

    for k in d.keys():
        print "%s: %d" % (k, d[k])
print countWord("Hello I am going to I with Hello am")
```

I want to learn how to find the word count.

Comment: `Hello` and `hello` are same?

Comment: Depending on your use case, there's one more thing you might need to consider: some words have their meanings change depending upon their capitalization, like `Polish` and `polish`.  Probably that won't matter for you, but it's worth remembering.

Comment: Could you define you data set more for us, will you worry about punctuation such as in  `I'll`, `don't` etc .. some of these raised in comments below. And differences in case?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you want to find the count of an individual word, just use `count`:

```
input_string.count("Hello")
```

Use `collections.Counter` and `split()` to tally up all the words:

```
from collections import Counter

words = input_string.split()
wordCount = Counter(words)
```

Comment: Is collections module part of basic python installation?

Comment: I'm copying part of a comment by @DSM left for me since I also used `str.count()` as my initial solution - this has a problem since `"am ham".count("am")` will yield 2 rather than 1

Comment: @Varun: I believe `collections` is in Python 2.4 and above.

Comment: @Levon: You're absolutely right. I believe using Counter, along with a regex word collector is probably the best option. Will edit answer accordingly.

Comment: Well .. credit goes to @DSM who made me aware of this in the first place (since I was using `str.count()` too)

Comment: why not just use len() instead of count()?
    words = input_string.split() ...
    wordCount = len(words)

Answer (score 6):

```
from collections import *
import re

Counter(re.findall(r"[\w']+", text.lower()))
```

Using `re.findall` is more versatile than `split`, because otherwise you cannot take into account contractions such as "don't" and "I'll", etc.

Demo (using your example):

```
>>> countWords("Hello I am going to I with hello am")
Counter({'i': 2, 'am': 2, 'hello': 2, 'to': 1, 'going': 1, 'with': 1})
```

If you expect to be making many of these queries, this will only do O(N) work once, rather than O(N*#queries) work.

Comment: +1 for re. `split` solutions won't work with phrases containing punctuations.

Comment: This is the best answer for me +1

Answer (score 6):

[`Counter` from collections](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#counter-objects) is your friend:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counts = Counter(sentence.lower().split())
```

Answer (score 4):

The vector of occurrence counts of words is called [bag-of-words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model).

Scikit-learn provides a nice module to compute it, [`sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html). Example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer = "word",   \
                             tokenizer = None,    \
                             preprocessor = None, \
                             stop_words = None,   \
                             min_df = 0,          \
                             max_features = 50) 

text = ["Hello I am going to I with hello am"]

# Count
train_data_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(text)
vocab = vectorizer.get_feature_names()

# Sum up the counts of each vocabulary word
dist = np.sum(train_data_features.toarray(), axis=0)

# For each, print the vocabulary word and the number of times it 
# appears in the training set
for tag, count in zip(vocab, dist):
    print count, tag
```

Output:

```
2 am
1 going
2 hello
1 to
1 with
```

Part of the code was taken from this [Kaggle tutorial on bag-of-words](https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial/details/part-1-for-beginners-bag-of-words).

FYI: [How to use sklearn's CountVectorizerand() to get ngrams that include any punctuation as separate tokens?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32128803/395857)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative, case-insensitive, approach

```
sum(1 for w in s.lower().split() if w == 'Hello'.lower())
2
```

It matches by converting the string and target into lower-case.

ps: Takes care of the `"am ham".count("am") == 2` problem with `str.count()` pointed out by @DSM below too :)

Comment: Using count by itself can lead to unexpected results, though: `"am ham".count("am") == 2`.

Comment: @DSM .. good point .. I'm not happy with this solution anyway since it's case sensitive, looking at an alternative right now ...

Answer (score 2):

Considering `Hello` and `hello` as same words, irrespective of their cases:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> strs="Hello I am going to I with hello am"
>>> Counter(map(str.lower,strs.split()))
Counter({'i': 2, 'am': 2, 'hello': 2, 'to': 1, 'going': 1, 'with': 1})
```

Comment: I would go with `Counter(strs.lower().split())`. Reduces some of the overhead for a faster runtime

Comment: Isn't this just Martijn Pieters' solution now, though?

Comment: @DSM I somehow didn't saw his solution, updated my solution back to the original version. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can divide the string into elements and calculate their number

`count = len(my_string.split())`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Python regex library `re` to find all matches in the substring and return the array.

```
import re

input_string = "Hello I am going to I with Hello am"

print(len(re.findall('hello', input_string.lower())))
```

**Prints:**

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def countSub(pat,string):
    result = 0
    for i in range(len(string)-len(pat)+1):
          for j in range(len(pat)):
              if string[i+j] != pat[j]:
                 break
          else:   
                 result+=1
    return result
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Your answer contains only code. It would be better if you could also add some commentary to explain what it does and how. Can you please [edit] your answer and add it? Thank you!