# Word frequency in a string without spaces and with special characters?

Tags: python, regex, string

Let's say I have the following string:

```
"hello&^uevfehello!`.<hellohow*howdhAreyou"
```

How would I go about counting the frequency of english words that are substrings of it? In this case I would want a result such as:

```
{'hello': 3, 'how': 2, 'are': 1, 'you': 1}
```

I searched previous question which were similar to this one but I couldn't really find anything that works. A close solution seemed to be using regular expressions, but it didn't work either. It might be because I was implementing it wrong since I'm not familiar with how it actually works.

[How to find the count of a word in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300383/how-to-find-the-count-of-a-word-in-a-string) 
it's the last answer

```
from collections import *
import re

Counter(re.findall(r"[\w']+", text.lower()))
```

I also tried creating a very bad function that iterates through every single possible arrangement of consecutive letters in the string (up to a max of 8 letters or so). The problem with doing that is

1) it's way longer than it should be and

2) it adds extra words. ex: if "hello" was in the string, "hell" would also be found.

I'm not very familiar with regex which is probably the right way to do this.

Comment: To count the frequency of english words, this is not sufficient. You'll have to use something like [ntlk](http://www.ntlk.org) and even then it'll be hard because you've got no separators for the words.

Comment: Do you have a function or dictionary for identifying english words?

Comment: I had a list of english words that I was comparing parts of the string with, but it didn't really help much.

Comment: @Howcan Please show us the list of english words you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d, w = "hello&^uevfehello!`.<hellohow*howdhAreyou", ["hello","how","are","you"]
import re, collections
pattern = re.compile("|".join(w), flags = re.IGNORECASE)
print collections.Counter(pattern.findall(d))
```

**Output**

```
Counter({'hello': 3, 'how': 2, 'you': 1, 'Are': 1})
```

Comment: @JayanthKoushik RegExs internally use state machines I believe. So, I am not very sure about the complexity. :(

Comment: You're using a list of known words to compare (w), so technically I'd have to use a list of english words?

Comment: @Howcan That is what I understood from this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21902569/word-frequency-in-a-string-without-spaces-and-with-special-characters/21903657?noredirect=1#comment33170204_21902569) of yours

Comment: you can use a dictionary or a library like enchant to make comparisons O(1).

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

s = 'hello&^uevfehello!`.<hellohow*howdhAreyou'
word_counts = defaultdict(lambda: 0)

i = 0
while i < len(s):
    j = len(s)
    while j > i:
        if is_english_word(s[i:j]):
            word_counts[s[i:j]] += 1
            break
        j -= 1

    if j == i:
        i += 1
    else:
        i = j

print word_counts
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract all words from the string, then for each word you need to find substrings and then check if any of the substring is english word. I have used english dictionary from answer in [How to check if a word is an English word with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788870/how-to-check-if-a-word-is-an-english-word-with-python)

There are some false positives in the result however so you may want to use better dictionary or have a custom method to check for desired words.

```
import re
import enchant
from collections import defaultdict

# Get all substrings in given string.
def get_substrings(string):
    for i in range(0, len(string)):
        for j in range(i, len(string)):
            yield s[i:j+1]

text = "hello&^uevfehello!`.<hellohow*howdhAreyou"

strings = re.split(r"[^\w']+", text.lower())

# Use english dictionary to check if a word exists.
dictionary = enchant.Dict("en_US")
counts = defaultdict(int)
for s in strings:
  for word in get_substrings(s):
      if (len(word) > 1 and dictionary.check(word)):
          counts[word] += 1

print counts
```

Output:

> defaultdict(, {'are': 1, 'oho': 1, 'eh': 1, 'ell': 3,
>   'oh': 1, 'lo': 3, 'll': 3, 'yo': 1, 'how': 2, 'hare': 1, 'ho': 2,
>   'ow': 2, 'hell': 3, 'you': 1, 'ha': 1, 'hello': 3, 're': 1, 'he': 3})

Comment: But that is not the desired output. Hell should be ignored if it is followed by an o etc. In general, all words which are substrings of other words in the string should be ignored.