# Transform every word in string to a dict and pass how many times all the word occured as value in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm having trouble transforming every word of a string in a dictionary and passing how many times the word appears as the value.
For example

```
string = 'How many times times appeared in this many times'
```

The dict i wanted is:

```
dict = {'times':3, 'many':2, 'how':1 ...}
```

Comment: Show your own (effort and) code properly formatted in the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I count unique words using counter library in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55987421/how-do-i-count-unique-words-using-counter-library-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

Using [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter
res = dict(Counter(string.split()))
#{'How': 1, 'many': 2, 'times': 3, 'appeared': 1, 'in': 1, 'this': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the words and increment the count like so:

```
d = {}
for word in string.split(" "):
   d.setdefault(word, 0)
   d[word] += 1
```