# How to use sklearn's CountVectorizerand() to get ngrams that include any punctuation as separate tokens?

Tags: python, nlp, scikit-learn, tokenize, n-gram

I use [sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) to compute n-grams. Example:

```
import sklearn.feature_extraction.text # FYI http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html
ngram_size = 4
string = ["I really like python, it's pretty awesome."]
vect = sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(ngram_size,ngram_size))
vect.fit(string)
print('{1}-grams: {0}'.format(vect.get_feature_names(), ngram_size))
```

outputs:

```
4-grams: [u'like python it pretty', u'python it pretty awesome', u'really like python it']
```

The punctuation is removed: how to include them as separate tokens?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should specify a word [tokenizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization_(lexical_analysis)) that considers any punctuation as a separate token when creating the [sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) instance, using the `tokenizer` parameter.

For example, [`nltk.tokenize.TreebankWordTokenizer`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#module-nltk.tokenize.treebank) treats most punctuation characters as separate tokens:

```
import sklearn.feature_extraction.text
from nltk.tokenize import TreebankWordTokenizer

ngram_size = 4
string = ["I really like python, it's pretty awesome."]
vect = sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(ngram_size,ngram_size), \
                                                 tokenizer=TreebankWordTokenizer().tokenize)
print('{1}-grams: {0}'.format(vect.get_feature_names(), ngram_size))
```

outputs:

```
4-grams: [u"'s pretty awesome .", u", it 's pretty", u'i really like python', 
          u"it 's pretty awesome", u'like python , it', u"python , it 's", 
          u'really like python ,']
```

Comment: ah but the counts are missing?

Comment: @alvas you can use  [`sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.transform`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.transform) to get the counts.

Comment: Thanks! I just wrote a bunch of crazy code to use sklearn learn to do ngram extraction and counts instead of native python and I'm timing it. Seems like native python wins =(