# Only words or numbers re pattern. Tokenize with CountVectorizer

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I'm using python `CountVectorizer` to tokenize sentences and at the same time filter non-existant words like "1s2".

Which re pattern should I use to select only English words and numbers? The following regex pattern gets me pretty close:

```
pattern = '(?u)(?:\\b[a-zA-Z]+\\b)*(?:\\b[\d]+\\b)*'

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 1),
                             stop_words=None,
                             token_pattern=pattern)
tokenize = vectorizer.build_tokenizer()

tokenize('this is a test test1 and 12.')

['this', '', 'is', '', 'a', '', 'test', '', '', '', '',
 '', '', '', '', 'and', '', '12', '', '']
```

but I can't understand why it gives me so many empty list items (`''`).

Also, how can I keep the punctuation? In end I would like to result like this:

```
tokenize('this is a test test1 and 12.')

['this','is','a','test','and','12','.']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know whether sklearn's CountVectorizer can do it in one step (token_pattern is overwritten by tokenizer, I think), but you can do the following (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32128802/how-to-use-sklearns-countvectorizerand-to-get-ngrams-that-include-any-punctua)):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from nltk.tokenize import TreebankWordTokenizer
import re

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,1), stop_words=None,
                             tokenizer=TreebankWordTokenizer().tokenize)
tokenize = vectorizer.build_tokenizer()

tokenList = tokenize('this is a test test1 and 12.')
# ['this', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'test1', 'and', '12', '.']

# Remove any token that (i) does not consist of letters or (ii) is a punctuation mark
tokenList = [token for token in tokenList if re.match('^([a-zA-Z]+|\d+|\W)$', token)]
# ['this', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'and', '12', '.']
```

EDIT:
I forgot to tell you why your answer doesn't work.

- "The default regexp select tokens of 2 or more alphanumeric characters (punctuation is completely ignored and always treated as a token separator)." ([How sklearn's token_pattern works](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html)). So punctuation mark is completely ignored.
- Your pattern `(?u)(?:\\b[a-zA-Z]+\\b)*(?:\\b[\d]+\\b)*` is actually saying: 'Interpret as unicode, word boundaries with letters in between (or not (the *)) and word boundaries with digits in between (or not (again a *))'. Because of all the 'or not', a pattern like '' (nothing) is also what you're searching for!