# Problems while TFIDF vectorizing tokenized documents?

Tags: python, regex, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp

I am vectorizing a text blob with tokens that have the following style:

```
hi__(how are you), 908__(number code), the__(POS)
```

As you can see the tokens have attached some information with `__(info)`, I am extracting key words using tfidf, as follows:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(doc)
indices = np.argsort(vectorizer.idf_)[::-1]
features = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
```

The problem is that when I do the above procedure for extracting keywords, I am suspecting that the vectorizer object is removing the parenthesis from my textblob. Thus, which parameter from the tfidf vectorizer object can I use in order to preserve such information in the parenthesis?

**UPDATE**

I also tried to:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

def dummy_fun(doc):
    return doc

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(
    analyzer='word',
    tokenizer=dummy_fun,
    preprocessor=dummy_fun,
    token_pattern=None)
```

and

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

def dummy_fun(doc):
    return doc

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(
    tokenizer=dummy_fun,
    preprocessor=dummy_fun,
    token_pattern=None)
```

However, this returns me a sequence of characters instead of tokens that I already tokenize:

```
['e', 's', '_', 'a', 't', 'o', 'c', 'r', 'i', 'n']
```

Comment: `tokenizer=dummy_fun` results in a list of characters because the tokenize needs to take in a string and return an iterable of tokens. Because `dummy_fun` returns a string, it's interpreted as an iterable of characters. Try `return doc.split()` instead.

Comment: Could you update your answer both with a regex and with a dummy method just for future reference to the community? @acattle

Comment: Is `doc` a single document or a list of documents? `TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform()` expects [a list of documents](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform), not a single document. Maybe try `vectorizer.fit_transform([doc])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that default tokenization used by [`TfidfVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) explicitly ignores all punctuation:

> token_pattern : string
>
> Regular expression denoting what constitutes a “token”, only used if analyzer == 'word'. The default regexp selects tokens of 2 or more alphanumeric characters (**punctuation is completely ignored and always treated as a token separator**).

Your problem is related to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32128802/how-to-use-sklearns-countvectorizerand-to-get-ngrams-that-include-any-punctua#32128803) but instead of treating punctuation as separate tokens, you want prevent `token__(info)` from splitting the token. In both cases, the solution is to write a custom `token_pattern`, although exact patterns are different.

Assuming every token already has `__(info)` attached:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(token_pattern=r'(?u)\b\w\w+__\([\w\s]*\)')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(doc)
```

I simply modified the default `token_pattern` so it now matches any 2 or more alphanumeric characters followed by `__(`, 0 or more alphanumeric or whitespace characters, and ending with a `)`. If you want more information on how to write your own `token_pattern`, see the Python doc for [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help!... for some reason I am getting: `ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words`

Comment: I updated with more info, thanks for the help again!

Comment: I changed the regular expression for `\S+__\([^()]+\)` and still having issues!

Comment: I fixed a small issue with my regex. I've verified the updated version tokenizes your strings properly however I can't reproduce your issue without knowing more about what `doc` contains.