# Know the number of times this word appears: PYTHON 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I have a file.txt with about 1,000 lines that look like this:

```
--- Adding sections to FwLogger: [],2020-01-13 16:09:18,2020-01-13 16:09:22 

--- Clearing all sections from FwLogger,2020-01-13 16:09:17,2020-01-13 16:09:22   
--- (1/0) The value was discarded due to being too separated from previous value    
--- (1/0) ContinueBoot@b7630fd  Rebooting device due to capabilities request freeze
```

And I would need to know how many times the word  "FwLogger" appears ( in number ).

Comment: Anything you have tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Read and include features from [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the count of a word in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300383/how-to-find-the-count-of-a-word-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely more elegant ways to do it, but in my version you replace the delimiters manually:

```
with open('test.txt') as file:
    for line in (line.strip() for line in file):
       #here you replace all possible delimiters in your file with a space to split afterwards according to the spaces
        c=line.replace(","," ").replace(";"," ").replace("@"," ").replace(":"," ")
        for word in c.split(" "):
            if word == "FwLogger":
#                print(line)
                counter= counter+1
                print(counter)
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct, if it helped you out.

Answer (score -1):

read in your txt file and use the string find method like below

loop

istart = str.find(sub, istart)

I= I + 1.

end loop

I start is the position where the string you're looking for was last found. before starting your loop assign istart = 1

each time one is found increment a counter

i.e. I= I + 1