# Returning the frequency of word list matched to a string

Tags: python, list, text

Here is an example of the problem with the result list as what I am aiming to obtain.

states = ["Montana", "New York", "Iowa", "Alabama", "Washington D.C."]
text = "Montana is big sky country where great ski slopes can be found. Avid skiers will enjoy Montana more than New York."

result = [Montana, Montana, New York]

One crude way I am looking at this is to do an intersection of the two but it is unable to handle duplicates and two word states like "New York".

```
state_lower = [x.lower() for x in states]
set(state_lower).intersection(text.lower().split())
```

I am looking for the fastest way to perform this operation as each text can be very long (4,000+ words) and I have millions of texts to go through. Also, I would like to keep the spaces in the original text. Thank you in advance.

Comment: 4000 words is nothing to a computer. Simply implement it the most straight forward way you can think of, then check if the time suits your needs. Premature optimization is the root of all evil

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410018/how-to-count-the-number-of-words-in-a-sentence-ignoring-numbers-punctuation-an

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300383/how-to-find-the-count-of-a-word-in-a-string

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268958/finding-occurrences-of-a-word-in-a-string-in-python-3

Comment: I've added some context here in that I have 3+ million texts to go through, each with 4,000 words.

Comment: Okay, that's ~60 GB of data. Maybe you want to start measuring performance on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> looking for the fastest way to perform this operation

Due to this I suggest giving a try [flashtext](https://pypi.org/project/flashtext/), you need to install it, which is done in standard way

```
pip install flashtext
```

Simple usage example with your data

```
from flashtext import KeywordProcessor
states = ["Montana", "New York", "Iowa", "Alabama", "Washington D.C."]
text = "Montana is big sky country where great ski slopes can be found. Avid skiers will enjoy Montana more than New York."
keyword_processor = KeywordProcessor()
keyword_processor.add_keywords_from_list(states)
result = keyword_processor.extract_keywords(text)
print(result)
```

output

```
['Montana', 'Montana', 'New York']
```

If you want to know how flashtext is working read [Replace or Retrieve Keywords In Documents at Scale by Vikash Singh](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.00046)

Comment: This is simplest solution for me to implement.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest in my opinion is to use a well crafted regex:

```
import re

regex = '|'.join(map(re.escape, states))

out = re.findall(regex, text)
```

output: `['Montana', 'Montana', 'New York']`

If you want to count:

```
import re
from collections import Counter

regex = '|'.join(map(re.escape, states))

out = Counter((m.group() for m in re.finditer(regex, text)))
print(dict(out))
```

output:

```
{'Montana': 2, 'New York': 1}
```

Comment: Great example once understood!

Answer (score 0):

```
states = ["Montana", "New York", "Iowa", "Alabama", "Washington D.C."]
text = "Montana is big sky country where great ski slopes can be found. Avid skiers will enjoy Montana more than New York."
for x in states:
    print(text.count(x),x)
2 Montana
1 New York
0 Iowa
0 Alabama
0 Washington D.C.
```

Comment: `print([text.count(x) for x in states])`

Answer (score 0):

Simply loop over all the strings in your states list and append the matches to a new list.

```
states = ["Montana", "New York", "Iowa", "Alabama", "Washington D.C."]
text = "Montana is big sky country where great ski slopes can be found. Avid skiers will enjoy Montana more than New York."

for state in states:
    if state.lower() in text.lower():
        for i in range(text.count(state))
            new_list.append(state)

print(new_list)
```

outputs:

```
["Montana", "Montana", "New York"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could mabe create little function for it.

```
wanted_countries = ['Montana', 'New York', 'Iowa', 'Alabama', 'Washington D.C.']

def filter_non_wanted(my_list):
   return_list = list()

   for INDEX, i in enumrate(my_list.split(' ')):
      if i == 'New' and my_list[INDEX+1] == 'York':
         return_list.append('New York')  
      elif i in wanted_countries:
         return_list.append(i)

      #-- second possibility, more flexible --#

      if ' '.join([i, my_list[INDEX+1]]) in wanted_countries:
         return_list.append(' '.join([i, my_list[INDEX+1]]))
      elif i in wanted_countries:
         return_list.append(i)
      return return_list
```

The second one is more "flexible" because you can simple add new `if` with like

`if ' '.join(list(np.append([i], my_list[from:to+1]))) in wanted_countries:`.